# Ruby script running standalone on vps

Tags: ruby, debian, vps

I have a ruby script that I want to run 24/7 on my vps( Debian Squeeze ).

Now to run that script I have to open a new ssh session with putty and start script by console.
When I close my console the script process also closes.

How can make my script running standalone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can take a look at the nohup command:

http://uw714doc.sco.com/en/SDK_tools/_Using_the_nohup_Command.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like tmux or screen and then run your script from within that. You only need to connect once, create a session and then you can close the connection without stopping the script. To gain control of your script you will need to reconnect and reattach to your previous session. See the tmuy or screen homepages for more information.